# 16 bit application in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

How to run 16 bit applications in Windows XP.
Turbo C is not working in WinXPSP3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can run Turbo C anywhere with [DOSBox](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/DOSBox.shtml).

here's a tutorial:

[Get a full-screened turbo c/c++ on windows Vista](http://vandit007.blogspot.com/2009/03/get-full-screened-turbo-cc-on-windows.html)

Answer (score 7):

Try running it in compatibility mode with Windows 95/98.

Right Click->Compatibility->Windows 98

Comment: As long as it's a 32bit XP...

Comment: how to know 32 bit/64bit.

Comment: I think you can safely assume that it is 32bit XP. Why don't you try it out and see if it works.

Comment: doesn't work for 16 bit applications